# Comparing two arrays with in_array function

Tags: php, laravel

I have two array I need to compare with in_array but for some reason it cannot compare, only if I replace manually like this in_array(294, $answer) it shows true.

```
$answers ----> // Array ( [0] => 294 [1] => 296 )
$answer  --->  // Array ( [id] => 294 [question_id] => 87 [correct] => 1 )
in_array($answers, $answer)
```

Comment: `in_array()` use for compare one string value with array not with both array. Use `in_array($answers[0], $answer)` or`array_intersact()`

Comment: You could try `$answer['id']`

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)? Also read about how to use the [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @RJParikh from manual: `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )` meaning in array can handle both strings and arrays as needle.

Comment: In in_array() function ,the first param must be a string,not array.

Comment: @Liu no it doesn't. Look at example three in the manual linked above.

Comment: If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner. @Andreas

Comment: Yes? What does that have to do with it? He wants to compare numbers (if I understand it correct) and numbers do not have uppercased versions.

Comment: Thank you all, I think array_intersact solved my problem , thanks RJParikh.

Comment: It's funny how all upvotes are in comments and all downvotes are in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an answer (`$answer = array('id' => 294, 'question_id' => 87, 'correct' => 1 );`) identified by `id` (value `294`) and you need to find out if this answer is one of the valid answers whose `id`s are stored in a list (`$answers = array(294, 296);`).

The PHP function [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is the tool to use, just use it the right way. Search the ID of `$answer` into the list of IDs stored in `$answers`:

```
$answer = array('id' => 294, 'question_id' => 87, 'correct' => 1 );
$answers = array(294, 296);

if (in_array($answer['id'], $answers)) {
    echo("Good answer");
} else {
    echo("Answer not found in list");
}
```

Read more about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and don't leave that reading until you reach the ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) section.

Comment: he want to check  `$answers` inside `$answer`. You did reverse of it.

Comment: @AlivetoDie what's the point of such need?

Comment: because may be his both array have more number of elements/sub-array, then  your code will stuck to first-iteration only. Currently OP' shows only single records in both array, but we have to consider every aspects

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` is used to search a string in an array, so you should try to pass a single value from answers array rather than whole array.

For example -

```
$answers = array(294, 296);
$answer = array('id' => 294, 'question_id' => 87, 'correct' => 1 );

foreach ( $answers as $answer_id ) {

    $check = in_array($answer_id, $answer);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $check );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Why `in_array($answer_id, $answer)`? The only place where the value of `$answer_id` can (and should) be found is `$answer['id']`.